# How to work with a statement: "for all $x$, if $p(x)$ then $q(x)$" (contradiction and contraposition)

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Proving by contradiction and contrapositive a statement of the sort "for all $x$, if $p(x)$ then $q(x)$"

Question about the notation: is it equivalent to $\forall x (p(x)\to q(x))$ or $(\forall x (p(x))\to q(x))$?

I know how to prove by contradiction and contra position the latter statement.

I want to make sure I know what to do with other statement: $\forall x (p(x)\to q(x))$

Proof by contradiction is: $\exists x (p(x)\wedge \neg q(x))$

Proof by contra position: $\forall x (p(x)\to q(x))\iff  (\forall x (p(x))\to \forall x (q(x)))\iff (\exists x (q(x))\to \exists x (p(x)))$

Are these correct?

Comment: @Regret does every statement have to define $x$?

Comment: It's related to my previous question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128733/proving-forall-x-in-mathbb-r-if-x0-then-x-frac-1-x-ge-2

Comment: I'm asking what $\forall x (p(x))\to q(x)$ means. Here the $q(x)$ is outside of the parenthesis.

Comment: @Regret is $∀x(p(x))→q(x)$ a false expression?

Comment: Since the $q(x)$ is outside of the $\forall x()$ block, it is a different $x$ than the one inside the $\forall x()$ block, which could be a bit confusing. Also, $x$ is not defined for $q(x)$ anywhere, so the truthfulness of the entire expression may depend on $x$.

Comment: Or did you mean $\forall x (p(x))\to \forall x(q(x))$ instead of $\forall x (p(x))\to q(x)$?

Comment: @Regret I meant what I wrote in the question, I had a feeling I was making an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement "for all $x$, if $p(x)$ then $q(x)$" is equivalent to $\forall x:(p(x) \rightarrow q(x))$

The statement $(\forall x:p(x)) \rightarrow q(x)$ is equivalent to "If for all $x$ $p(x)$, then $q(x)$."

The statement $\forall x (p(x) \rightarrow q(x))$ is not equivalent to $\forall x p(x) \rightarrow \forall x q(x)$. For example the sentence "For every car: if it is not moving then it is still" is equivalent to "For every car: it is moving or it is still" but this is NOT the same as "For every car:it is moving OR For every car: it is still".

Comment: Why is the implication became "or" in your example? And how do you actually do a contra position on this statement?

Comment: Because $p \rightarrow q$ is logically equivalent to $\lnot p \lor q$. Since $\lnot q \rightarrow \lnot p$ is the contraposition of $p \rightarrow q$ your statement is equivalent to $\forall x:(\lnot q(x) \rightarrow \lnot p(x))$

Comment: So we don't touch the outer quantifier? so $ ∀x(p(x)→q(x))$ is equivalent to $∀x(p(x)\wedge \neg q(x))$?

Comment: No, $\forall x(p(x) \rightarrow q(x))$ is equivalent to $\forall x:(\lnot p(x) \lor q(x))$ That's right, we leave the outer quantifier be.

Comment: The tautologies (K.0)-(K.1) on this sheet might be useful to you: http://www.math.ethz.ch/~halorenz/4students/logikGT/Tautologien.pdf

Comment: I didn't use the right words, is the negation of $∀x(p(x)→q(x))$ is  $∀x(p(x)∧¬q(x))$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20733/discussion-between-longeyes-and-kuhaku).

Answer (score 1):

$$
\forall x\big(p(x)\big) \,\to\, q(x)
$$
cannot be correct, since the first part, the assumption,  $\forall x\big(p(x)\big)$ DOES NOT depend on $x$, while the second part, the conclusion,  $q(x)$ DOES depend.

Comment: I see.. Is the way I worked with the other statement correct btw?